# Using `StackExchange.Precompilation`, how can I output build errors?

Tags: c#, serialization, exception, metaprogramming, roslyn

I am using `StackExchange.Precompilation` to perform some C# syntax transformations on build.  I would like to be able to throw exceptions from my `ICompileModule` during the build and have those output to Visual Studio's output window.

I have created a custom exception type `PrecompilationException` to represent errors that occur during these syntax transformations.  Here is my exception class:

```
[Serializable]
public class PrecompilationException : Exception {

    public PrecompilationException() : base() { }

    public PrecompilationException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public PrecompilationException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    protected PrecompilationException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

When one of these exceptions is thrown, the output window shows a `SerializationException` whose message is *"Type is not resolved for member 'PrecompilationException..."*, but there are no details of that `PrecompilationException` like its message or stack trace.

Did I leave out something important for proper serialization in my exception class?  Is there a better way to get `StackExchange.Precompilation` to log errors?

---

**Update**
If I change the exception type being throw to something standard like `Exception` or `NotSupportedException` the output window will show the exception details.  However, I would still like to be able to use custom exception types in this way.

**Update2**
The answer to this question sheds some light on why my custom exception type was not working. Basically, the ASP.NET compiler has trouble serializing types that aren't in the GAC.

[Type resolution error during ASP.NET precompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020503/type-resolution-error-during-asp-net-precompilation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a [`Diagnostic`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Diagnostic/Diagnostic.cs) to the `Diagnostics` collections in [`Before`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation/blob/73c9a6b3deeb9f37e8f0300aa60a543dd5527825/StackExchange.Precompilation.Metaprogramming/BeforeCompileContext.cs#L15)/[`AfterCompileContext`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation/blob/73c9a6b3deeb9f37e8f0300aa60a543dd5527825/StackExchange.Precompilation.Metaprogramming/AfterCompileContext.cs#L20).

The other alternative is to `Console.WriteLine` in the [MsBuild VS-Aware error message format](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2006/11/02/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If I use a `Diagnostic`, the build seems to ignore warnings and fails on errors, but there isn't any related information in the Output or Error List windows.  The formatted `Console.WriteLine` approach emits errors/warnings to the Error List window, but I'm having trouble translating a `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Location` into the line/column numbers required by that format.  Is there anything special I need to do to get `Precompilation` to emit diagnostics to the Error List?  Or, is there a way to get line/column numbers easily from syntax objects?

Comment: Console.WriteLine on a Diagnostic.ToString should be in the correct format already

Comment: I was actually not initializing my `DiagnosticDescriptor` propertly.  It works with either mode you suggested now.  Thanks again!